# Search strings for individual words from another string in Python

Tags: python, search, csv

My question has several issues to address. I need to import a csv file with two fields (a number field used as an ID, and a string field used as a description). Then, convert the string field to a set (list? tuple? dict?) of individual words and search each other set to count the matches.

example:

```
id_field | desc_field
1        | some description
2        | some other description
3        | some third other description
```

what I need out of this is a list of id_field matches

```
id_field 1 has 2 matches in id_field 2
id_field 1 has 2 matches in id_field 3
id_field 2 has 3 matches in id_field 3
```

etc

Importing the `csv` file should be easy enough to do using:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('SOMEFILE.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'
```

I'm sure I can handle finding and counting the words using the find or in operators, but I'm having trouble writing code that will let me search the csv string field.

Comment: Hi John! Welcome to SO. I don't understand what you're asking for. Could you clarify it?

Comment: Which scores for desc_field ``1`` if there are also the following lines:  ``4 | some description in other order`` and ``5 | some description blue otherwise`` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('SOMEFILE.csv'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
data = [[line[0], line[1].split()] for line in reader]

for no1, words1 in data:
    for i in range(int(no1), len(data)):
        no2, words2 = data[i][0], data[i][1]
        matches = len(words1 + words2) - len(set(words1 + words2))
        print 'id_field', no1, 'has', matches, 'matches in id_field', no2
```

Let me know if you have any problems or questions about the code. I have assumed that you only want to check forwards like in your example i.e. when on 1 check for matches with 2 and 3, when on 2 just check 3 (if there were 3 rows).

If you wanted to exclude cases with zero matches, you could just add the following line before the print and indent the print:

```
if matched > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv  
import itertools
import re

id_2_desc = {}

with open('SOMEFILE.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')

    for n, (id_field, desc_field) in enumerate(reader):
        if n > 0:
            id_2_desc[id_field.strip()] = desc_field.strip()


id_fields = id_2_desc.keys()


for id_field1, id_field2 in itertools.combinations(id_fields, 2):
    desc_field1 = id_2_desc[id_field1]
    desc_field2 = id_2_desc[id_field2]

    desc_tokens1 = re.split('\s+', desc_field1)
    desc_tokens2 = re.split('\s+', desc_field2)

    matches = set(desc_tokens1) & set(desc_tokens2)

    print 'id_field {} has {} matches in id_field {}'.format(id_field1, len(matches), id_field2)
```

Comment: You can shun the use of ``enumerate`` by doing: ``csvfile.readline()``at first